# How do I create a directory structure?

Tags: terminal, macos, folders

I ran these commands to make the directory:

```
mkdir webpack-demo
cd webpack-demo
npm init -y
npm install webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack-cli --save-dev
```

and then type `cd webpack-demo`, then if I type `ls` I get "node_modules"       "package-lock.json" "package.json"

but then when I attempt to follow the next instructions from the [webpack basic set up instruction page:](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#basic-setup)

```
  webpack-demo
 |- package.json
+ |- index.html
+ |- /src
+ |- index.js
```

I get the following output from terminal:

```
|- package.json
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
+ |- index.html
-bash: +: command not found
-bash: -: command not found
+ |- /src
-bash: +: command not found
-bash: +: command not found
+   |- index.js
-bash: +: command not found
-bash: -: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those aren't commands, it's a diagram of the directory tree you're creating.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions use the same formatting for commands you need to enter and for output, which is confusing. Just use `mkdir` to create any missing directories.

PS: It *seems* as if the directory structure within `webpack-demo` is created automatically by the various commands you run (or are supposed to run), so you may not even need to create additional directories yourself.